# Get sender's full name using javamail

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

Can you please tell me how I can get the full name of the sender from a `MimeMessage` using `JavaMail`? I tried to get the personal from the address, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If InternetAddress.getPersonal() isn't returning the full name, then the sender didn't include the full name in the message they sent.  Or, if you're using IMAP, your mail server is failing to return the full name properly.  The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) will provide more information.

Comment: thank you bill. yes, getPersonal returns null. I thought there are other methods, considering the fact that the email were sent from gmail website and I don't think that gmail isn't sending this informations. Anyway, I solved it by querying my database after users email,though I know it's not efficient. I will keep it as a temporary solution until I find a way to pick senders full name from the MimeMessage.

Comment: Again, the debug output will show you whether that information is even in the message at all, and whether the server is sending it to you.  What mail server are you using?